# Predicting nested categorical variables from a set of continuous predictors

Tags: classification, matlab, neuroscience, neuroimaging

My dataset contains multiple continuous predictors (responses from n neurons) from which I would like to predict two categorical variables (A and B), where B is nested under A. A can take 8 different values, while B can take only 2 values within each level of A. My question is, what would be the best model to use this in this case to predict A and B from my predictors?

My goal is to predict A and B from neural data collected under different conditions and see how the predictions compare to across (A and B) and within variable types (A or B under different conditions).

Here is an example MATLAB code that can be used to generate the surrogate data:

```
N = 50; % number of neurons
T = 100; % number of trials
K = 8; % number of categories for variable A

for iT = 1:T
  neural_response{iT,1} = randn(N, 1); % generate vector of neural population response
end

% generate variable A
A = randi(K, T, 1); % randomly assign one of K categories to each time point

% generate variable B within each level of variable A
B = zeros(T, 1);

for k = 1:K
  idx = A == k; % find time points corresponding to category k
  B(idx) = randi(2, sum(idx), 1) - 1; % randomly assign 0 or 1 to each time point
end

% combine into a table
neural_data = table(neural_response(:), A, B, 'VariableNames', {'neural_response', 'A', 'B'});
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!